# dynamic callback with omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I use omniauth for Facebook Authentification in my app. All works great. Now I try to implement a callback to a dynamic page which is the ID of an article.

The URL follows the pattern myapp.com/ads/:id/
On this page I use the auth gateway to /auth/facebook
The callback should come back exactly to this page (e.g. /ads/4711/).

I tried to accomplish this in routes:

```
match "/auth/facebook/callback" => "/ads/:id/"
```

which is obv not valid.
Also tried to work out this solution [OmniAuth dynamic callback url to authenticate particular objects instead of current_user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533064/omniauth-dynamic-callback-url-to-authenticate-particular-objects-instead-of-curr) with no success.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to schieve, could you make it clear please?

Comment: What if you receive callback as usual and then redirect?

Comment: Ok to make it more clear:
Let's say we are on a dynamic page /ads/4711 - the ID gets fetched via params['id'] and releases some content on that page based on the ID (that's why it is dynamic). Now a user Facebook auth himself - sees the Facebook auth page and after successfully logging in, he should get redirected to the very same page he came from. (in this case: /ads/4711) - I need to somehow pass the ID to the Facebook auth page and get it back after the call back (if this is the solution) but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution via [Devise + Omniauth - How to pass extra parameters along?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657727/devise-omniauth-how-to-pass-extra-parameters-along)

I can easily pass the ID as a param to the auth page and get it back via `request.env['omniauth.params']`